# Error while loading eclipse (Not able to run any android application)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

Yesterday i updated my android sdk to api 17. Now the launching of eclipse is showing error (image 1)[image: when eclipse id launched]

I tried to check for updates but its not allowing.

I also have my android sdk path mentioned in preference but then also it says that "Android SDK path not mentioned in prefrence"

And when I try running any application it shows (image2) [image: when running any application]

When I am trying to update my adt 20 to 21 then also there is a error (image 3)
[image]
Please help me. Because of this I am not able to proceed ahead.

Comment: which link you are using to update ADT because in above image that shown link is for installing JAVA decompiler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says your current ADT plugin is 20.0.3. And you require Version 21.x.x for API level 17.

So, to fix this, open eclipse->help->install new software and then select ADT plugin. it will display the latest ADT version. click next and continue.

Comment: Extract a new copy of eclipse. Install ADT plugin and then set the Android SDK preference. that would do for sure.

Answer (score 0):

To configure SDK, go to `Windows>>Preferences>>Android` and put your SDK location Sample location would be `C:\Android\android-sdk-windows`
I suppose that would solve your issue

If you already have SDK installed then please update SDK
go to `Help>>Check for updates`

Comment: I tried this but its not working and anyways in preferences  there is android sdk path present.

Comment: Please update your SDK then. Your issue would be sorted out then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be just to remove your SDK and then [redownload the bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).